# what are the profiler tools available for play framework?

Tags: playframework, profiling

i have a task to do profiling play framework application,can anyone tell me what are the best tools for doing profiling on play framework application?
also share some links here.
thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can use all profilers that work with the JVM like YourKit.

Answer (score 2):

Play says that they are using [YourKit](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.4/ThirdPartyTools), so I think it is the best if even framework creators use it for the framework in the process of development this framework.